# Eclipse Dynamic web project 6.0 is not option to deploy to server (wildfly 28)

Tags: java, eclipse, wildfly

I have a Dynamic Web Project 6.0 in eclipse and go to option Run as / Debug as and I can't see add to server.

Only I can to deploy if I mark the application as deployable.

Environment

> Eclipse Version: 2023-03 (4.27.0) | Build id: 20230309-1520 | Oracle JDK 17

[image: project Structure]

[image: Deployment Assembly]

Let's me know all thing that I did wrong please